# Excel VBA - Loop search for value then color row

Tags: vba, excel, search, user-input

This macro is supposed to find the value ***NULL*** in column "**W**" and paint the row it found NULL on in a color. It does that fine however if I try to search for a number in the same column(that i know exists there) it doesn't seem to find the value. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub e()

MsgBox "some question?", , "Marvin The Paranoid Android"

Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, wb As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, sht As Worksheet
Dim myValue As Variant

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Èçáåðåòå ôàéë ñ èìå /Ðåâîëâèíãè/")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)
Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
X = wb.Name

Windows(X).Activate

'Macro optimization
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'000000000
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
Rows("1:1").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("A1:W1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range("A:E,L:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 6.14
Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 6.43
Columns("H:K").ColumnWidth = 5.43
Range("O:R,T:V").ColumnWidth = 4.71
Columns("S:S").ColumnWidth = 14.71
Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 54.54
Range("A1").Select

myValue = InputBox("Give me some input")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).row

For r = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(r, Columns("W").Column).Value = myValue Then
        Rows(r).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next r

Range("A1").Select
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

wb.Close SaveChanges:=True 'or false

'Reverse macro optimization
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox "Îáðàáîòèõ ôàéë /Ðåâîëâèíãè/...", , "Marvin The Paranoid Android"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there more than one sheet in the workbook? `Windows(X).Activate` activates the workbook.

Comment: There is Workbook A that contains all macros and from where they all run. Windows(X) is the second workbook that the macros do their magic on (Workbook B for example). There is only 1 sheet in Workbook B

Comment: Im still sort of new to Excel VBA and Im not entirely sure what "fully qualify a line" means.

Comment: Maybe you need to fully qualify this line: `If Cells(r, Columns("W").Column).Value = myValue Then` to `If sht.Cells(r, Columns("W").Column).Value = myValue Then`.

Comment: Tried it and it didnt change anything. The macro still finds "NULL" just fine but cannot find "0" or any other number I put in the input box.

Comment: you can use `If Cells(r, "W").Text = myValue Then` instead of Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Autofilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx)() method of `Range` object can detect "23" both as number and a text:

```
With sht
    With .Range("W1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp)) '<--| consider column "W" values down to its last non empty row
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=myValue '<--| filter column "W" on 'myValue'
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any values match...
            With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior '<--|... consider only filtered values, and apply formatting
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    End With
    .ShowAllData '<--| show all rows back...
End With
```

Comment: works great! Thank you! Works both with NULL and numeric values and numbers like 72.4 and such

Comment: Had to test it out a bunch of ways just because im so happy it works. It took me a couple of hours of searching before I gave up and asked here. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

When you say:-

> if I try to search for a number in the same column(that i know exists there) it doesn't seem to find the value

I assuming you are referring to the below line from your code not returning true and running the code within the If statement.

```
If Cells(r, Columns("W").Column).Value = myValue Then
```

In short, if its not finding a match then there is not a match, but it can be hard to see sometimes.

Examples of not matching when you think it should are:-

- If the cell contains `12.12121212` but is formatted to show it as `12.12`, if you search for `12.12` (as you think that would match) it will not match.
- If the cell contains leading or trailing spaces, `'12.12 '` (space at the end), if you search for `12.12` (no space at the end) it will not match.

We can see what you are trying to match or what you think should be a match from your question but the above should be the information needed to work the answer out from your content.

Based on the comments, try altering your code with the below, I've added some debugging lines to help understand why its failing: -

```
'If the value is null it will skip trying to check it, this mean no type mismatch error
If Not IsNull(Cells(r, Columns("W").Column).Value) then

    'This prints the value in the cell, the searched value, and if its seen as a match
    Debug.Print "'" & Cells(r, Columns("W").Column).Value & "' ,'" & myValue & "', " & (Cells(r, Columns("W").Column).Value = myValue)

    'Compares them both as Long data types
    If CLng(Cells(r, Columns("W").Column).Value) = CLng(myValue) Then
       'Your code
    End If

End If
```

Comment: So here is what values column "W" holds - W1 - header, W2 - 0, W3 - 3, W4 - 7, W5 - NULL and so on and so forth. With different numeric values with a couple of NULLs in between. I am certain the column contains 0 when I am searching for it but it just skips it. Where as NULL is found without issue.

Comment: @ShaiRado May have the right idea here, `0` is not the same as `"0"` (as in one is a number and one is a string containing a number). Try as he mentioned `CInt(myValue)`.

Comment: You can also drop `Cells(r, Columns("W").Column).Value`,  `myValue`, and `Cells(r, Columns("W").Column).Value = myValue` into the immediate pane to get an idea of what is happening.

Comment: with CInt(myValue)

when I input exactly this "0" i get Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch
when I input exatly this 0 it just doesnt find it in the column
when I input exactly this NULL i get Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch
when I input exactly this "NULL" i get Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: @Shakdun, try my solution with `Autofilter`: it picks up text and numbers and zeros

Comment: I think the immediate window will fix this one to help understand why the values are not pairing up but I have updated my answer with a little bit more to see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `For` loop with the piece of code below.
If you are using Decimal values, or values larger than Integer, make the changes from ***CInt*** to your needs:

```
For r = 1 To LastRow
    If sht.Cells(r, "W").Value = CInt(myValue) Then
        sht.Rows(r).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: Still misses numeric values but now causes an error when searching for NULL which is necessary from time to time.

Comment: @Shakdun share the search options you are looking to have , like numeric values range, strings, Null, whatever...

Comment: Numeric values from 1 to 200 without decimals just normal numbers ( cant remember the word, english isnt my main language) and NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your loop with this:

```
Dim tempFind
Set tempFind = ActiveSheet.Columns("W").Find(What:=myValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
If Not tempFind Is Nothing Then
    With Range(tempFind.Address).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Not Found!"
End If
```